# Extract "Urls" FROM Json-Data with Imacros

Tags: imacros

I'm using iMacros for Firefox and want to extract some urls from a JSON file
I Tried to extract these urls

```
http://www.google.com,
http://www.yahoo.com,
http://www.amazon.com
```

**The JSON file looks like this:**

```
{
      "names": {
        "name": "websites"
      },
      "urls": [
        {
          "id": 10,
          "url": "http://www.google.com"
        },
        {
          "id": 11,
          "url": "http://www.yahoo.com"
        },
        {
          "id": 12,
          "url": "http://www.amazon.com"
        }
      ]
    }
```

[image]

**My IMACROS CODE :**

```
VERSION BUILD=8601111 RECORDER=FX
TAB T=1
SET !ENCRYPTION NO
WAIT SECONDS=1
TAG POS=1 TYPE=TD ATTR=TXT:url  EXTRACT=TXT
TAG POS=2 TYPE=TD ATTR=TXT:url  EXTRACT=TXT
TAG POS=3 TYPE=TD ATTR=TXT:url  EXTRACT=TXT
SAVEAS TYPE=EXTRACT FOLDER=* FILE=links.txt
```

Thanks .

Answer (score 1):

Try to play this macro:

```
SET !EXTRACT_TEST_POPUP NO
TAG POS=1 TYPE=* ATTR=* EXTRACT=TXT
SET !EXTRACT EVAL("var u = []; var a = JSON.parse('{{!EXTRACT}}').urls; for (i in a) u.push(a[i].url); u.join('[EXTRACT]');")
SAVEAS TYPE=EXTRACT FOLDER=* FILE=links.txt
```

Comment: Thank you Sir @Shugar , but i have this Error .... " allocation size overflow, line: 4 (Error code: -1001) " .....

Comment: Erorr from line : `TAG POS=1 TYPE=* ATTR=* EXTRACT=TXT`

Comment: `VERSION BUILD=8601111 RECORDER=FX
TAB T=1
SET !EXTRACT_TEST_POPUP NO
TAG POS=1 TYPE=* ATTR=* EXTRACT=TXT
SET !EXTRACT EVAL("var u = []; var a = JSON.parse('{{!EXTRACT}}').urls; for (i in a) u.push(a[i].url); u.join('[EXTRACT]');")
SAVEAS TYPE=EXTRACT FOLDER=* FILE=links.txt`